# ORACLE SQL Replace null values with previous value depending on other fields

Tags: oracle, replace, null

From a query I want to replace the null values of the "cod_account" field, the condition to fill this field is that it must take the previous value only if it satisfies that the previous records of other fields (cod_agen, cod_sub, no_prod) are equal.
Currently it is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEKxJ.png)

what is desired is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUbOV.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of text/data.  Nobody can run a query against that. WHat have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your advice. i solve it

use with to separate queries.

```
select

   case when cod_account is null and class ='Primary'
   then null
  when cod_account is null and class='Secundary'
  then (select cod_account from principals P--principals is table create in a "with"
         where fa.cod_agen=P.cod_agen
         and fa.cod_sub=P.cod_sub
         and fa.no_prod=P.no_prod
         and p.class='secundary'



   )
...

from signs fa
```